# Raspberry Pi zero w enable AP mode when writing the image to connect to the RPi with SSH without the need for a monitor or WiFi

Tags: pi-zero-w, access-point, hotspot

- physical device: raspberry pi zero w
- os: raspberry pi OS lite 32bits
- SD card: samsung evo+ 64GB
- powering mode: laptop USB

I am trying to configure my RPi zero w to broadcast its own WiFi network so that I can connect to it via SSH without any external WiFi nor monitor. The tricky part is that I would like to do it before inserting the SD card in the RPi, because I don't have access to the RPi once I insert the SD card in.

I saw this [cool guide](http://blog.hoxnox.com/gentoo/wifi-hotspot.html) but it is using commands that I cannot enter in the RPi.

What is the best way to achieve that ? Should I create a sh script named "firstrun.sh" on the SD card and put every commands from the guide ? Is there a special config line that would do it for me ? Should I create a hotspot with my phone and then connect both my computer and my RPi to it ?

Thank you and have a great day

PS: could anyone create the tag "first-boot" ?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point

Comment: @Dougie maybe I didn t use the right wording but I am not looking for an ethernet connection (which doesn t exist on a zero w).

Comment: Creating such a script would be possible. First YOU have to work out WHAT is needed (which most people would do with a keyboard and monitor) THEN write a script to automate it. Frankly setting up a headless machine is a non trivial task.

Comment: ok thank you, I guess I ll go with one of my alternative solution !